# PHP Array Break Down/Explode

Tags: php, arrays

**STARTING ARRAY**

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /searchnew.aspx?Make=Toyota&Model=Tundra&Trim=CrewMax+5.7L+V8+6-Spd+AT+SR5&st=Price+asc
        [1] => 19
    )
 )
```

I have been struggling to break down this array for the past couple days now. I have found a few useful functions to extract the strings I need when a start and end point are defined, however, I can't see that being good for long term use. Basically I'm trying to take the string relative to [0], and extract the strings following "Model=" and "Trim=", in hopes to have array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => Tundra ***model***
    [1] => CrewMax+5.7L+V8+6-Spd+AT+SR5 ***trim***
    [2] => 19
 )
)
```

I'm getting this information fed through an api, so coming up with a dynamic solution is my biggest challenge. I realize this a big question, but is there a better/less hacky way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**parse_url()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will get you the query string and [**parse_str()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) parses the variables from that:

```
$q = parse_url($array[0][0], PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($q, $result);

print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [Make] => Toyota
    [Model] => Tundra
    [Trim] => CrewMax 5.7L V8 6-Spd AT SR5
    [st] => Price asc
)
```

Now just `echo $result['Model']` etc...

Comment: Minor correction, given the input in the OP it should be `$array[0][0]`

Comment: This is perfect! A lot cleaner than the road I was going down- thanks a bunch.